# Increase the thickness of an arrow in xy and tikz-cd package

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd, xy-pic, ticks, tikzset

We start from these simples MWE. The first is done with `xy` package, with your tips:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \ar[r]& B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and with the same tips of `tikz-cd`,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \ar[r]& B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code with `tikz-cd` is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

> How can I increase the thickness of an arrow in `xy`? I've read the basic `xy` guide but couldn't find anything. With `tikz-cd` package there is a command called `\tikzcdset`. How is it possible to set it to have such an arrow as the picture below?

[image]

**Follow-up 2021-6-4:** I have found the solution of my problem (using `dvips`),
but my code not works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dvips,color,matrix,arrow,all,cmtip}{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{ A\ar@*{\color{black}}@*{[|<5pt>]}[rrr] &&& B}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

```
LaTeX Error: File `dvips.sty' not found. [...ackage{dvips,color,matrix,arrow,all,cmtip}{]
```

> Is it possibile to reopen my question?

Comment: with xy you are using a _font_ for the arrowhead, with tikz you are drawing it. Obviously you have more options if drawing the shape than selecting a character from a font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As always I thank you so much. I absolutely did not know that with *xy* there was a font. I read the guides for what that I understand of the English language :-)

Comment: (+1): I’m voting to close this question because solved in the comments, **hope that's ok**!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Oh, there is not problem for the closure. You have done well.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Hi, I think that the solution exist. I have done an edit but the new code actually not work. Bye :-)

Comment: Waiting for reopening: `\ar@*{[|<5pt>]}@[green][r]` will produce an arrow with 5pt thickness and colored green. But you need to compile with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`.

Comment: All clear, I voted for re-opening.

Comment: @egreg Very kind egreg, yes I have seen the 5pt of tickness and color green. So starting with the simple pdfLaTeX the code doesn't work? I remember that latex+dvips+ps2pdf it is the canonic compilation of TeXnicCenter if I remember well.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you very much for the reopen my question.

Comment: @downvoter: What is the real reason for your downvote? Please, can you explain your downvote here?

Comment: What about trying with `\usepackage[dvips,color,matrix,arrow,all,cmtip]{xy}`?

Comment: @Werner Very kind Werner I actually have taken the entire package code from one of my not too old applications and pasted it in. You're absolutely right, matrix is not needed, but I put the entire code into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the width of the arrows, but this is only available with the `dvips` driver.

I think it might be extended to the PDF driver, but it seems that development of Xy-pic has been stopped for several years.

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvips,color,all,cmtip]{xy}
\UseCrayolaColors

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@C+2pc{
 A\ar@*{[|<5pt>]}@[ForestGreen][r] & B \\
 A\ar@*{[|(10)]}@[Dandelion][r] & B
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]