# Triangular Commutative Diagram in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I have made the following diagram. But I want the arrow to thick and long. How to do it?

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]

X \supseteq \phi^{-1}(V) \arrow{r}{\varphi}  \arrow[swap]{rd}{f \circ \varphi} 

  & V \subseteq Y \arrow{d}{f} \\

    & k
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

First off, you specified `column sep=small` which reduces the arrow length. With `column sep=large`, for example, they will be longer. Then you can specify the arrow tip style with a `tikzcdset`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,diagrams={line width=2pt,>={Stealth[round,length=8pt,width=5pt,inset=2.75pt]}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
    X \supseteq \phi^{-1}(V) \arrow{r}{\varphi}  \arrow[swap]{rd}{f \circ \varphi} & V \subseteq Y \arrow{d}{f} \\
        & k
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikzcd arrow tip]

As for the line thickness, thanks to egreg, you can do it by adding an `append style` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzcdset{
    every arrow/.append style={line width=1pt},
    arrow style=tikz,
    diagrams={line width=2pt,>={Stealth[round,length=8pt,width=5pt,inset=2.75pt]}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
    X \supseteq \phi^{-1}(V) \arrow{r}{\varphi}  \arrow[swap]{rd}{f \circ \varphi} & V \subseteq Y \arrow{d}{f} \\
        & k
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: with the line width]

Comment: Hi, you can see this my recent question....https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596366/increase-the-thickness-of-an-arrow-in-xy-and-tikz-cd-package

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, of course, I was referring to this question in my answer. But egreg found a way to increase the line width in his answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Making diagrams with the `psmatrix` environment is another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{psmatrix}%[column sep=large]
X \supseteq \phi^{-1}(V) & V \subseteq Y \\
& k
\psset{arrowinset=0.12,linejoin=1, arrows=->, labelsep=1pt}
\ncline{1,1}{1,2}\naput{\varphi}
\ncline{1,1}{2,2}\nbput[nrot=:U]{f \circ \varphi}
\ncline[nodesep=2pt]{1,2}{2,2}\naput{f}
\end{psmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One more `tikz-cd` solution with using `mathrlap` in placement od top right node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large,
every arrow/.append style={-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},semithick}
                 ]
X \supseteq \phi^{-1}(V)
  \rar["\varphi"]
  \drar["f \circ \varphi"'] 
    &  V \mathrlap{\subseteq Y}
      \dar["f"] \\
    & k
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure you want thicker arrows. Anyway, here it is, with some changes to make the arrows pointing to the correct object.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={line width=0.6pt}]
\makebox[0pt][r]{$X \supseteq{}$} \phi^{-1}(V)
  \arrow[r,"\varphi"]
  \arrow[rd,"f \circ \varphi"'] &
V \makebox[0pt][l]{${}\subseteq Y$}
  \arrow{d}{f} \\
& k
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It might make sense to issue the change to `line width` the default: issue

```
\tikzcdset{
  every arrow/.append style={line width=0.6pt},
}
```

in the document preamble.

For comparison, here's the output without changing the line width.

[image]